# database login failure by using Crystal Report 9.2 in .net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 9.2 in vb.net.Whenever i run the project on other computer,it appears the login and password box for database and can't show the crystal reports.What shoul i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your datasource. It has to be correct. Plus try running the setup at your system also.
This should help also you
Can you also show your code for displaying the report